# Database.SetInitializer is not seeding the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, code-first

I am using `enitity framework version 6.1.0 code first approch`. The database is just creating fine but when come to seeding part it is not seeding the override Seed Method.

How do i make to seed my data?

My testing implementation is as

```
public class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Categories>();
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required,StringLength(100),Display(Name="Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Categories>  Categories{ get; set; }
}

public class Categories
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required,StringLength(100),Display(Name="Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }

}
```

The ProductsInitializer is inherited from DropIfModelchanges

```
 public class ProductsDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ETestContext>
 {
    protected override void Seed(ETestContext context)
    {
        GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
        GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }

    private static List<Categories> GetCategories()
    {
        var categories = new List<Categories>{
            new Categories{
                CategoryId=101,
                Name="Electronics"
            },
            new Categories{
                CategoryId=102,
                Name="Clothing"
            }
        };
        return categories;
    }

    private static List<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        var products = new List<Products>{
           new Products{
             CategoryId = 101,
             ProductId=1,
             Name="Laptops"
           },
           new Products{
             CategoryId = 101,
             ProductId=2,
             Name="Desktops"
           },
           new Products{
             CategoryId = 102,
             ProductId=3,
             Name="Male Clothing"
           },
           new Products{
             CategoryId = 102,
             ProductId=4,
             Name="Female Clothing"
           }
       };
        return products;
    }


}
```

And My DBcontext class is as

```
public class ETestContext : DbContext
{

    public ETestContext()
        : base("ETest")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().HasMany<Products>(c => c.Products).WithMany(p => p.Categories)
            .Map(c =>
            {
                c.MapLeftKey("CategoryId");
                c.MapRightKey("ProductId");
                c.ToTable("CategoryProduct");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

In the global.asax I am implementing as

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Database.SetInitializer(new Wb1.Model.ProductsDatabaseInitializer());
   using (var dbContext = new Wb1.Model.ETestContext())
   {
     if (!dbContext.Database.Exists())
     {
       dbContext.Database.Create();
     }
     dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `Database.SetInitializer<ETestContext>(new Wb1.Model.ProductsDatabaseInitializer());`

Comment: in Application_Start, do you need this ?using (var dbContext = new Wb1.Model.ETestContext())
   {
     if (!dbContext.Database.Exists())
     {
       dbContext.Database.Create();
     }
     dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
   } , I thought EF framework will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Initialize` instead of `Create`, it has different implementation with the initializer.

> Creates a new database on the database server for the model defined in
>   the backing context. Note that calling this method before the database
>   initialization strategy has run will disable executing that strategy. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.create%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

And since `ProductsDatabaseInitializer` is `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, the moment you call `Initialize`, the database has been created so that the `Seed` method will not be executed, but if there is a model change, the `Seed` method will be executed because it's dropped and recreated.

The proper way should be just calling the `Initialize` without checking if it exists or not, because it's already derived from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, which means create if it doesn't exists and execute the `Seed` method, or drop and create if model's changed and execute the `Seed` method, otherwise do nothing.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new Wb1.Model.ProductsDatabaseInitializer());
using (var dbContext = new Wb1.Model.ETestContext())
{
    dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```